# Почему у меня ошбика Syntax in my pygame code?

Tags: python, pygame

Ошибка:

```
line 35
    if <= current_ray NUM_RAYS - 1 and distance_to sprite < walls[current_ray][0]:
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Код:

```
import pygame
from settings import *

class Sprites:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sprite_types = {
            'barrel':pygame.image.load("sprites/barrel/0.png").conver_alpha()}
        self.sprite_objects = [
            SpriteObject(self.sprite_types['barrel'], True,(7.1,2.1),1.8,0,4),
            SpriteObject(self.sprite_types['barrel'], True,(7.1,2.1),1.8,0,4),
        ]


class SpriteObject:
    def __init__(self, object , static , pos , shift , scale):
        self.object = object
        self.static = static
        self.pos = self.x,self.y = pos[0] * TILE, pos[1] * TILE
        self.shift = shift
        self.sclae = scale

    def object_locate(self,player,walls):
        dx , dy = self.x - player.x, self.y - player.y
        distance_to_sprite = math.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2)

        theta =math.atan2(dy,dx)
        gamma = theta - player.angle
        if dx > 0 and 180 <= math.degress(player.angle) <= 360 or dx < 0 and dy < 0:
            gamma += DOUBLE_PI

        delta_rays = int(gamma / DELTA_ANGLE)
        current_ray = CENTER_RAY + delta_rays
        distance_to_sprite *= math.cos(HALF_FOV - current_ray * DELTA_ANGLE)

        if <= current_ray NUM_RAYS - 1 and distance_to sprite < walls[current_ray][0]:
            proj_height = int(PROJ_COEFF / distance_to sprite * self.scale)
            half_proj_height = proj_height // 2
            shift = half_proj_height * self.shift
            sprite_pos = (current_ray * SCALE - half_proj_height, HALF_HEIGHT - half_proj_height + shift)
            sprite = pygame.transform.scale(self.object,(proj_height,proj_height))
            return (distance_to_sprite, sprite,sprite_pos)
        else:
            return (False,)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if` должен выглядеть так:

```
if a <= b:
```

а у вас :

```
if <= a b:
```

поэтому

```
if <= current_ray NUM_RAYS - 1
```

надо заменить:

```
if current_ray <= NUM_RAYS - 1
```

Comment: спасибо  я  не внимателен